# VLFeat's Image Mosaicing in Matlab

Tags: sift, homography, vlfeat, mosaic, ransac

The following is a piece of code that forms a Mosaic of two images after computing the Homography Matrix H using RANSAC pror to which SIFT was used to compute the descriptors:

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                               Mosaic
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
box2 = [1  size(im2,2) size(im2,2)  1 ;
        1  1           size(im2,1)  size(im2,1) ;
        1  1           1            1 ] ;
box2_ = inv(H) * box2 ;
box2_(1,:) = box2_(1,:) ./ box2_(3,:) ;
box2_(2,:) = box2_(2,:) ./ box2_(3,:) ;
ur = min([1 box2_(1,:)]):max([size(im1,2) box2_(1,:)]) ;
vr = min([1 box2_(2,:)]):max([siize(im1,1) box2_(2,:)]) ;
[u,v] = meshgrid(ur,vr) ;
im1_ = vl_imwbackward(im2double(im1),u,v) ;
z_ = H(3,1) * u + H(3,2) * v + H(3,3) ;
u_ = (H(1,1) * u + H(1,2) * v + H(1,3)) ./ z_ ;
v_ = (H(2,1) * u + H(2,2) * v + H(2,3)) ./ z_ ;
im2_ = vl_imwbackward(im2double(im2),u_,v_) ;
mass = ~isnan(im1_) + ~isnan(im2_) ;
im1_(isnan(im1_)) = 0 ;
im2_(isnan(im2_)) = 0 ;
mosaic = (im1_ + im2_) ./ mass ;
figure(2) ; clf ;
imagesc(mosaic) ; axis image off ;
title('Mosaic') ;
if nargout == 0, clear mosaic ; end
end
```

Now I understand we need to warp the images in someway before stitching them using the computed Homography? 
What then, is the logic behind the definition of **"box2"** i.e why consider the size of the first and second dimension of im2? Also, what is the function of **mass** and the lines of code that follow?

Answer (score 1):

The content of `box2` is simply the bounding box (corner coordinates) of the second image; `box2_` is then this bounding box transformed into the coordinate system of `im1` - in which you compute the range of coordinates (`ur` and `vr`) where to project `im2` after transformation.

The purpose of variable `mass` is just to indicate how many images cover each pixel: If only one image is nonempty at a given pixel, its `mass(...)`=1 and the result equals to the value from this image. If both images are nonempty, `mass(...)`=2 results in computing their mean value.